# Attempting to set a stringproperty to default of a md5 of another part of model

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

What I am trying to do is on the fly when storing an image to the datastore, I would like to fill in a entry with the md5sum of the image for use later when outputting the image.  I feel like it is a dummy error that I have over looked and just cant see right now.

Code snippet:

```
import hashlib

from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
from google.appengine.ext import db

def getimg(url):
    result = urlfetch.fetch(url)
    if result.status_code == 200:
        return result.content
    else:
        return None

class ImageBlobs(db.Model):
    img = db.BlobProperty(default=None)
    last_update = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
    etag = db.StringProperty(default=hashlib.md5(img).hexdigest())

img = ImageBlobs(img=getimg('http://www.a-real-domain.com/a-working-image.png'))
img.put()
```

The error:

```
TypeError: must be convertible to a buffer, not BlobProperty
```

Ideas/Suggestions on what I can do to solve my little problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defaults don't work that way. You need a [DerivedProperty](https://github.com/Arachnid/aetycoon/blob/master/__init__.py#L26):

```
@DerivedProperty
def etag(self):
  return hashlib.md5(self.img).hexdigest()
```

Comment: By the way, this won't save effort computing it at read-time - it'll just make it indexable.